# How do I show extra option on checked checkbox?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ngselect

I've got dropdown:

```
<ng-select [items]="items" bindLabel="name" ngModel name="dropdown" formControlName="dropdown" required></ng-select>
```

Here are items:

```
 items = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Option 1'
    }, 
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Option 2'
    }, 
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Option 3'
    }, 
    { //extra option
      id: 4,
      name: 'Option 4'
    },
  ]
```

I want the extra item (option 4) to be hidden. When he user click on checkbox, the extra option shows up. How do I do that?

My checkbox:

```
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin" ngModel name="checkbox" formControlName="checkbox">Show hidden option!</mat-checkbox>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add additional array `itemsToShow` which will be used in ng-select.
Original array will be used just as a data source.
Then on checkbox change assign to `itemsToShow` the original array or  filtered one by id field (depending on the current checkbox value).

Component:

```js
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {
    checkbox = new FormControl(false);

    items = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Option 1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Option 2' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Option 3' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Option 4'},
    ];

    itemsToShow = [];
    itemIdToHide = 4;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.itemsToShow = this.getFilteredItems([this.itemIdToHide]);

        this.checkbox.valueChanges.subscribe((checked) => {
            if (checked) {
                this.itemsToShow = [...this.items];
            } else {
                this.itemsToShow = this.getFilteredItems([this.itemIdToHide]);
            }
        });
    }

    private getFilteredItems(idsToHide: number[]): { id: number; name: string }[] {
        return this.items.filter((item) => !idsToHide.includes(item.id));
    }
}
```

Template:

```js
<ng-select [items]="itemsToShow" bindLabel="name" ngModel name="dropdown" formControlName="dropdown" required></ng-select>
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [formControl]="checkbox">Show hidden option!</mat-checkbox>
```

Note, `getFilteredItems()` method can filter by multiple ids.